# Australia: Multiple-entry visa (Temporary work permit, for Subclass 400)

Tags: indian-citizens, australia, multiple-entry, business-travel

I am from India and applying for a Subclass 400 visa with multiple entry. I am planning for a 90-day visit to Australia. I would like to know if it is possible to travel back to India after 30 days of visit due to a possible emergency, stay in India for 20 days and then fly back to Australia.

Comment: Isn’t that what ‘multiple entry’ means?

Comment: @Traveller Not really. There is a cooling off period in some countries ( Like the US). You can't have a B1 visa and keep exiting and entering every other week. That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, if you have a multiple entry visa.  However, the 3-month clock does not stop when you leave Australia.  So in your example above, when you return to Australia you can only stay for 3 months minus 50 days (i.e. 39 to 42 days depending on which month you first arrive).

More information can be found on the [Department's website](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/400-?modal=/Visas/supporting/Pages/400/how-many-times.aspx):

> - If you are granted a multiple entry visa, you will be able to travel to and from Australia as many times as you want while your visa is valid. If you need to make a number of return visits during your period of stay you should tell us in the visa application form, including the reason why you need to make the return visits to Australia.
> - Your stay period begins on the day you first enter Australia. Re-entering Australia does not start a new period of stay.